# Sudden drop in training error despite smoothly-varying learning rate?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions

I trained my model for 10 epochs using the FastAI library, and observed sharp drops in the error at the start of each epoch (first plot). However when I plot the learning rate, it's shown to be smoothly varying over the entire course of training (second plot).

[image]

Given my understanding of the 1-Cycle training policy, I would have thought that the learning rate would vary cyclically over the course of training, with 1 cycle per epoch. This would also explain the loss drop-offs that I'm seeing. Is the second plot simply inaccurate here?

I trained the model with

```
learn.fit_one_cycle(10, 1e-3, moms=(0.8,0.7))
```

And I plotted the data with:

```
learn.recorder.plot_losses()
learn.recorder.plot_lr()
```